# Error of "encountered a second time" by find.pm

Tags: linux, perl, deployment

everyone,

when I deploy my package to a linux environment, I met this **error**:

```
.../Linux-2.6c2.5-i686/Ncurses/Ncurses-15766.0-0/lib/libncurses.so.5 is encountered a second time at /apollo/_env/FBAMerchantAutoRemovalDaemon-swit1na.1755067.237551097.1107633519/perl/lib/perl5.8-dist/File/Find.pm line 542.
```

though I read the `perl` script, I have no idea what is wrong. I suspect my environment is tainted. Does anyone have idea what is wrong and how can I debug this problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

Zhe

Comment: File::Find is a module to traverses a directory structure much like the `find` utility. *`follow_skip==1`, which is the default, causes all files which are neither directories nor symbolic links to be ignored if they are about to be processed a second time. If a directory or a symbolic link are about to be processed a second time, File::Find dies.* It sounds like `.../Linux-2.6c2.5-i686/Ncurses/Ncurses-15766.0-0/lib/libncurses.so.5` is a symlink to a file it already encountered. It can't tell if this is a problem, so its default behaviour is to die (throw an exception) in that situation.

Comment: I can't help you more than this because, like F::F, I don't know/understand the context.

Comment: Thanks, ikegami! yes, libncurses.so.5 is a symbolic link to libncurses.so.5.3. So libncurses.so.5.3 is observed 2 times to cause the problem? And I don't understand why this check is valuable? Why it is an error if a symbolic link or directory is observed 2 times? Does that mean in my folder that are multiple symbolic links to the same file?

Comment: @HouZhe What if you are using the existence of a file to start a major database update that will take up significant resources? `File::Find` cannot know if it is OK to do that twice or more.

Comment: Re "*And I don't understand why this check is valuable?*", F::F is being instructed to execute code for each file it encounters. It has no way of knowing if it's safe to execute that code twice for one file. (Also, encountering a directory twice indicates an infinite loop.) The coder can instruct F::F that it's safe to encounter a file twice if it's safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [perldoc File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find)

> #### `follow`
>
> Causes symbolic links to be followed. Since directory trees with symbolic links (followed) may contain files more than once and may even have cycles, a hash has to be built up with an entry for each file. This might be expensive both in space and time for a large directory tree. See "`follow_fast`" and "`follow_skip`" below. If either `follow` or `follow_fast` is in effect:
>
> It is guaranteed that an `lstat` has been called before the user's `wanted()` function is called. This enables fast file checks involving `_`. Note that this guarantee no longer holds if `follow` or `follow_fast` are not set.
>
> There is a variable `$File::Find::fullname` which holds the absolute pathname of the file with all symbolic links resolved. If the link is a dangling symbolic link, then fullname will be set to `undef`.

So, if, for the purposes of your application, if it is OK to follow symlinks, invoke `find` with the `follow` option set:

```
find({ wanted => \&process, follow => 1 }, $dir);
```

Or, consider if one of the other `follow_skip` behaviors is more appropriate for your application:

> #### `follow_skip`
>
> `follow_skip==1`, which is the default, causes all files which are neither directories nor symbolic links to be ignored if they are about to be processed a second time. If a directory or a symbolic link are about to be processed a second time, `File::Find` dies.
>
> `follow_skip==0` causes `File::Find` to die if any file is about to be processed a second time.
>
> `follow_skip==2` causes `File::Find` to ignore any duplicate files and directories but to proceed normally otherwise.

It may be that `follow_skip => 2` is more appropriate for *your* application. Only you can make that decision.

Comment: But what if you find that while you're installing something, and not in your code? And what causes it?